# How to get the value of Seekbar for calculation?

Tags: java, android

Above the generateData() method, i declared an integer variable bw, i want it to be equal to the value of the current seekbar progress, how to do that? or actually can i directly use the value of progress for calculation??
Sorry it may sound a stupid question but i am absolute new to programming.

If I put bw=progress; inside the onprogresschanged, the outcome of bw*10 and bw*9 will become 0 no matter how i slide the seekbar.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int bw;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, generateData());
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        final TextView seekBarValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valuetextview);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                bw=progress;
                seekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

        });

    }



    //Detail of drugs in following formatL "Drug Name", doseperkg,"frequency"
    private ArrayList<DrugItem> generateData() {
        ArrayList<DrugItem> items = new ArrayList<DrugItem>();
        items.add(new DrugItem("Ceclor", bw * 10, "mg every   8 hours"));
        items.add(new DrugItem("Cedax", bw * 9, "mg every 24 hours"));
        items.add(new DrugItem("Zinnat", bw * 10, "mg every 12 hours"));
        items.add(new DrugItem("Zithromax", bw * 10, "mg every 24 hours"));


        return items;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes obvious.

In below method  **int** ***progress*** this is your main point value. U can use it for calculation .

but make sure work around in **onProgressChanged** method.

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
// your calculation...


            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, but i want the value inside the arraylist to be updated upon changing the value of progress. Or how to pass the progress value out?

Comment: make one method with parameter like
ABC(progress) inside onprogrsschange ..
and ABC have arraylist u can use progress value at there

Answer (score 0):

in the callback methods of seekbar

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                bw=progress;
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

        });
```

in addition to that you may want to set a maximum value to seekbar's seek

`seekBar.setMax(max_value-min_value);`

Comment: i put bw=progress; as suggested but the value of bw*10 at the end is 0 no matter how i slide the seekbar?

Comment: @SimonHo paste the new code changes in original post.

Comment: @SimonHo call `generateData() ` after `bw=progress;`